# How to convert array of float into 365-calendar daytime? (excluding leap year)

Tags: python, numpy, netcdf, python-xarray

I have a `nc` file in which the day unit is off.

```
<xarray.DataArray 'days' (time: 6570)>
array([730817., 730818., 730819., ..., 737384., 737385., 737386.])
Dimensions without coordinates: time
Attributes:
    units:      days_since_Jan11900
    long_name:  calendar_days
```

I want to convert these into a date without taking leap year into consideration, as my data is on a 365-day-a-year calendar, meaning there is no such thing as a leap year in the dataset. I have tried this

```
ds['days'] = ds.days - 730817
ds.days.attrs['units'] = 'days since 2001-05-30'
```

But, the leap year in 2004 then gives me one day earlier than the previous three years. Hence, it begins on May 29th but that is not correct, as it is actually May 30th due to the 365-day-a-year-calendar.
What I want is my time unit to constantly show a period ranging from May 30th to Aug 18th, 2001, May 30th to Aug 18th, 2002, and so on even in leap years. So basically substitute my ranges with:

```
<xarray.DataArray 'days' (time: 6570)>
array([30-05-2001, 31-05-2001, ..., 18-08-2001, ..., 18-08-2015, 30-05-2016, ...,])
```

How can I do that?

EDIT
I now tried to include @spencerkclark's method.

```
ds['days'] = ds.days - 730817
ds.days.attrs['units'] = 'days since 2001-05-30'
ds['days'].attrs['calender'] = 'noleap'
ds = xr.decode_cf(ds)
```

But, I still get Feb 29th in the leap years. Therefore, my very last date is shifted backwards to `2099-11-02` while it should stay at `2099-12-31`. So not entirely fixed, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a calendar attribute to the `'days'` coordinate and xarray will decode the times assuming a `'noleap'` calendar into `cftime.DatetimeNoLeap` objects:

```py
ds['days'].attrs['calendar'] = 'noleap'
ds = xr.decode_cf(ds)
```

Comment: If I combine the `ds['days'] = days.ds - 730966` + `days since xxxx` with your answer, the `ds.days` variable still includes Feb 29th for every leap year. Therefore, my very last date is `2099-11-02` but should be `2099-12-31. Do you know what I am doing wrong? And, thanks for the answer @spencerkclark

Comment: It looks like you may have misspelled "calendar" in your code above :).  It should end in "ar" instead of "er."  Could you try again with the correct spelling?

Comment: Haha, true! Appreciate it big time @spencerkclark! This made it for me, I have been struggling for too long with this problem. Thank you from the bottom of my heart.